# Video file size problem when using 60 fps using CameraX API in android

Tags: android, kotlin, frame-rate, android-camerax

we are developing an android app which uses camerax api for video recording.We tried to capture 60 fps video and for this we extended camera2 feature in our code.Here is a snippet of our code

```
    private fun startCameraatf60() {
    viewBinding.flash.isChecked=false
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        val preview = Preview.Builder().apply {
            setTargetResolution(Size(1080,1920))

        }
        val exti = Camera2Interop.Extender(preview)
            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_USE_SCENE_MODE)

            .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(60,60))
        val s = preview.build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(viewBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
            .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.FHD))
            .build()
        videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)}
```

But the main problem when 60 fps is being used ,video size(in mb) captured by app is far less than the video size which are captured by device's default camera.Through the app captured video size is around 7 mb and by device's default camera video size is around 50 mb.Can anyone please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no requirement for a device manufacturer to expose the same capabilities that its own camera app uses through public camera APIs for other apps to use. Beyond that, you would need to identify what the camera-related characteristics are of the two files that explain the size difference (e.g., different resolution, different bit depth).

Answer (score 1):

you should try it with lower bit rate,
i know there is a function that call "setBitRate" that can help you.

here is example of my code with java:

```
videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(1080, 1920))
            .setVideoFrameRate(60)
            .setBitRate(512 * 1000)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this information for a long time, it helped me a lot, thanks to you!